# Confused about my iPhone XS Max min-width

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

When I view a webpage in Safari on my iPhone XS Max, the following javascript statements output **Portrait logical resolution / pixels: 414x896 / 1242x2688** as expected.

```
<script>
document.write("Portrait logical resolution / pixels: " +screen.width + "x" + screen.height + " / ");
document.write(screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio + "x" + screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio + "<br>");
</script>
```

I also have in CSS the following definitions:

```
@media screen and (min-width:800px) {
    .minWidth:after{
        content: '800px';   
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:900px) {
    .minWidth:after{
        content: '900px';   
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1000px) {
    .minWidth:after{
        content: '1000px';  
    }
}
```

I am surprised to see on the page that the following line
`<span class="minWidth">Min Width: </span>` outputs:
**Min Width: 900px**

This means that the device's min-width >= 900px and < 1000px. This however doesn't agree with  the device's Portrait logical resolution / pixels being **414x896 / 1242x2688**

Any explanation to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `viewport` meta tag to my webpage solved the problem.

Apple documentation says about the `viewport` meta tag (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html):

"Use the viewport meta tag to improve the presentation of your web content on iOS. Typically, you use the viewport meta tag to set the width and initial scale of the viewport. For example, if your webpage is narrower than 980 pixels, then you should set the width of the viewport to fit your web content. If you are designing an iPhone or iPod touch-specific web application, then set the width to the width of the device. Refer to Supported Meta Tags for a detailed description of the viewport meta tag."

I added the following line to my webpage's header:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

And now Javascript's `screen.width` is consistent with @media `min-width` value.

On my iPhone XSmax I get:

Portrait logical resolution / pixels: 414x896 / 1242x2688

Min Width: 400